# Chain parameters with multiple RewriteRules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get the `language` and the `page` a user is on.

A typical URL might look like `example.com/fr/login` which means they're on the `fr` language, on the `login` page.

The language part is also optional, URL could also look like `example.com/login` (in which case I check if the user has a language cookie else I show English by default).

So my .htaccess looks like:

```
# if url contains login, then route to page.php
RewriteRule login/?$ /page.php?login [QSA]

# if start of url contains a language param,
# make it available as a GET param for PHP to use
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)(?:/([^/]+))?$ $2?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The result I need is that if we are on the page `login`, then `page.php` should receive `$_GET['lang']` (with value `fr`) and `$_GET['login']` (no value, just its existence lets me know we're on the login page). Similarly if we're on for instance `example.com/fr` then index.php would have `$_GET['lang']` available.

Note that I have many pages and many languages, so if you have in mind to just duplicate rules with all possible scenarios, then it may not be the best way to scale many pages and many languages.

Edit: Still testing if it's fine, but made some progress by doing:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|it)/?login$ /index?page=login&lang=$1 [QSA]

# Catch the rest
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|it) ?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```